# How to validate a ridge regression model?

Tags: validation, ridge-regression, regression-strategies

How do I validate a ridge regression model? Presently I am using both the mean absolute error and the $R^2$ score from python's `sci-kit learn`, and am plotting the prediction against the actual result.

Is this enough? I am having a bit of a tough time finding information which is written in layman's terms.

Comment: Could you tell us a little more specifically what "validate" means to you?  It potentially has various different meanings, such as to check goodness of fit (a form of "internal validation") or "external validation" (testing it against known responses for data independent of the data used to fit the model).

Comment: Ideally both internal and external validation. I am doing this for a university project and it is a heading in our write up and I want to make sure I have covered all bases when it comes to validation

Comment: Is there some aspect of ridge regression that suggests it might require (or be amenable to) validation methods any different from standard methods to validate any other regression model?  If not, that would open up a lot of resources for your research.  If so, it would be of interest to know what that special aspect is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using cross-validation to find the best lambda that fits your need. R's glmnet package can perform cross-validation for a grid of values for lambda. As per the plot shown below, the model with 2 variables gives the model with the least MAE. I am pretty sure that there would a Python package that has the same functionality. A quick Goolging gave me [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV.html) , hope this was useful.
[image]